# What are the rules for building user phrases and Google responses (OnOff and Cook traits)?

Tags: google-smart-home

Current documentation doesn't fully describe the rules for how a user can build the phrases to trigger any operation and possible answers. Could you please provide the following:

1. for "action.devices.traits.OnOff" trait:

   - the full set of phrases that user can use to trigger turning on/off OR rules to build them;
   - possible response phrases from Google Assistant if turning on/off was started successfully OR rules to build them.
2. for "action.devices.traits.Cook" trait (for two ways of parameters combination: cookingMode + foodPreset  OR cookingMode + foodPreset  + quantity + unit (ounces)):

   - the full set of phrases that user can use to trigger cook operation OR rules to build them;
   - possible response phrases from Google Assistant if cook operation was started successfully OR rules to build them;
   - the full set of phrases that user can use to cancel cook operation OR rules to build them;
   - possible response phrases from Google Assistant if cancellation of cook operation was started successfully OR rules to build them.
3. what additional words could the user add when framing this phrase for these two traits? For example, “me”, “please”, “my new {foodPreset}”, “a cup of {foodPreset}” (“cup” is not a “unit”) and any other words and phrases. What are the rules for this?
4. are there any recommendations for “foodPreset” parameter (words amount, words complexity)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no strict rules. Traits can be triggered through natural language processing, so you may expect any relevant phrase should work. The documentation provides examples for [OnOff](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/onoff) and [Cook](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/cook) but aren't limited by the provided phrases.

Responses also are based around good voice design and natural language, so there aren't any strict rules to what you'd expect. Additionally, such requests and responses may change as the platform continues to evolve. The NLP system is able to extract meaning from larger statements, so general things like "turn on the light", "turn on the light please", and "please turn on the light for me" should all match.

With regards to `foodPreset`, the key can be whatever you want for your service. The synonyms should be fairly varied and include any possible way that an individual would refer to that food item.

Comment: We are facing incorrect recognition. For example, "brew 6 oz of coffee", "brew me coffee" and "turn on coffee maker" work, but "brew 6 oz coffee", "brew me coffee on my machine" and "turn on brewer" don't work. Could you please clarify if there is a way to improve Smart Home recognition? Is it learning continuously during user interaction? Do you have support team to collect all these cases to improve current behavior? Could you please recommend any approach, that could help us?

Comment: If there are any statements that do not work, I suggest filing [an official bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) to improve the grammars.